# css - right-align an pointer in a dropdown

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a Bootstrap dashboard by [Creative Tim](https://www.creative-tim.com/product/light-bootstrap-dashboard-pro/), and trying to add a dropdown list to a table cell as in typical Boostrap:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Link1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Link2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

however this particular styling adds a pointer to the dropdown list which is nice and beautiful but is left-aligned:

[image]

How do I transform the styles of this pointer so it is right-aligned?

The styles do exist for this behaviour - see dropdowns at the top of the page:

[image]

but I cannot reproduce it outside the navigation panel.

I've uploaded the page in question here (there are to many styles there to upload to JSFiddle):
http://fredapps.s3.amazonaws.com/light-bootstrap-dashboard-pro/examples/tables/regular2.html

Comment: Can't access this link, access is denied.

Answer (score 0):

The way he seems to do it on [his live preview](http://demos.creative-tim.com/light-bootstrap-dashboard/dashboard) is simply through CSS. So if I were you I'd take a look there and see what's different on yours. My screenshot shows the `:before` pseudo-element, make sure you look at the `:after` as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The top navigation style overrides the `left` value for `:before` and `:after`.

The default styles look like this:

```
.dropdown-menu:before {
    border-bottom: 11px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-left: 11px solid transparent;
    border-right: 11px solid transparent;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 12px;
    top: -11px;
}

.dropdown-menu:after {
    border-bottom: 11px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-left: 11px solid transparent;
    border-right: 11px solid transparent;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 12px;
    top: -10px;
}
```

Update them with:

```
... {
  left: auto;
  right: 12px;
}
```